# 'getElementById' on HTMLelement

Tags: javascript, html

I have a simple site. It does a fetch to another html page. That's working and I have some response. Now I want a part of the page and select the id
'test' from the HTML. Now I created a HTMLelement, but how can I select a part of it?

How can I do this without adding all the HTML to the dom.

```
<html>

<body>

  <script>
    // in real it's a fetch with response text:
    const HTML = `<div id="">I dont need this</div>
               <div id="test"> I want this</div>`;
    const EL = document.createElement('html')
    EL.innerHTML = HTML;
    console.log(EL);
    // This is not working, but I want to do this
    console.log(EL.getElementById('test'));
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is not working, because you did not append `EL` to your current document yet. You would need to do that _before_ the method to select an element by ID _in the current document_ could find it. But appending this to the document first probably makes rather little sense (especially when you create `html` as the root node for that element), so you should perhaps rather use `querySelector` - that can be called on any element node, and not just document.

Comment: Sorry, yes I want to get it from the EL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a  `new DOMParser()`:

```js
// in real it's a fetch with response text:
const HTML =  `<div id="">I dont need this</div>
               <div id="test"> I want this</div>`;
const EL = new DOMParser()
            .parseFromString(HTML, "text/html")

console.log(EL.getElementById('test'));
```

Comment: Great and clean.

Comment: Just a note. If you want to add it to the DOM now use: element.appendChild(EL)

Answer (score 1):

The trick here is to create a **new DOM** that you can add the content to instead of creating a second HTML element belonging to your existing document.

```js
var parser = new DOMParser();
var htmlDoc = parser.parseFromString('<div id="parent"></div>', 'text/html');

const html = `<div id="">I dont need this</div>
               <div id="test"> I want this</div>`;
const el = htmlDoc.getElementById('parent');
el.innerHTML = html;
console.log(el);
// This is not working, but I want to do this
console.log(htmlDoc.getElementById('test'));
```

Alternatively, you can create an element belonging to the existing document and search it with `querySelector` (which can be called on an element) instead of `document`.

```js
const html = `<div id="">I dont need this</div>
               <div id="test"> I want this</div>`;
const el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = html;
console.log(el);
// This is not working, but I want to do this
console.log(el.querySelector('#test'));
```